# CSS Layout: Elements overlay after slideDown() called

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, adobe-edge

I have a menu button that when clicked, calls `slideToggle()` on a `<div>` with a `<ul>` in it. In Chrome and Firefox on desktop, it displays like this:

[image]

That is, the element slides down and pushes the content below it down. That's the expected behavior.

In Chrome and Safari for iOS7 (as well as in Adobe Edge Inspect) and the Android browser on 4.1.2, however, the menu overlays the element below it in the DOM:

[image]

### What I've Tried

- Our good friend `z-index` (higher on the `<ul>`, even tried negative on the element below it)
- I've tried every permutation of `display` CSS properties on both elements (e.g., `block`, `display-block`).
- I've tried every permutation of `position` properties (one with `absolute`, the other with `relative`; one with `static`, the other with `relative`, etc.)
- I've tried every permutation of floating and unfloating both elements.
- I've tried adding a hard-coded height property to the menu
- Worked with margins and padding

Note: Unfortunately, this is in a dev environment, so it's not anywhere that you can test it. I will, however, update with a js fiddle.

### Edit

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/8sXY4/1/) a fiddle, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with the media queries.

### Edit 2

It actually works on my phone in that fiddle, so it must be some other CSS I have.

### Edit 3

I tried commenting out [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/), the framework I'm using, and that still happens. It must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can we have a link to the website?

Comment: It's in a dev environment. localhost is the only way to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after bisecting our entire 20,000+ line CSS in the entire application, it comes down to this.

The containing element of the nav, `<div class="header-container">` had a height property of `height: 50px` in the CSS. Apparently, the desktop browsers I tried interpret a `slideDown` as making an allowance for the height of the containing element growing, and mobile browsers don't.

Changing that property to `min-height: 50px` solved this issue.